# Sending ASCII Control Characters to Serial Device using libserial on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port

I have a very basic device with which I am trying to interact via a serial connection on Linux. I am on the steep part of the learning curve here, still, so please be gentle!

One of the functions involves sending data to an attached printer. You send a command to the device, which then relays the data you input to the printer attached to the device. The command looks like this:

- Send "EXEX*". The device echoes back "EXEX" (the '*' is not echoed yet)
- Send a single byte indicating the length of the data you will send, including a LF at the end.
- Send the data (the device will now echo back the *).
- Send "#". The device will now be ready for another command.

I have a small C++ program to communicate with the device, and I can successfully send single characters and such, but when I try to send this command, I do not get the expected results.

Using Hyperterminal in Windows, it is particularly easy, using alt-key combinations to send ASCII control codes. Just connect and:

- Type "EXEX*"
- Type Alt+010 to send a LF character, indicating that you are sending 10 bytes to the printer (nine characters and a LF).
- Type the data you wish to send: "123456789" (nine bytes in length).
- Type Alt+010 again to send a final LF character to the printer.
- Type "#" to finish.

Here is what I cobbled together to try in C++:

```
#include <SerialStream.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace LibSerial;

int main(){
char buffer [50];
int n;

n=sprintf (buffer, "EXEX*%c123456789%c#",10,10);
printf("Variable buffer was set to a %d character string: %s\n",n,buffer);

SerialStream my_serial_stream;
my_serial_stream.Open("/dev/ttyS0") ;
my_serial_stream.SetBaudRate( SerialStreamBuf::BAUD_19200 ) ;
my_serial_stream.SetCharSize( SerialStreamBuf::CHAR_SIZE_8 ) ;
my_serial_stream.SetFlowControl( SerialStreamBuf::FLOW_CONTROL_NONE ) ;
my_serial_stream.SetParity( SerialStreamBuf::PARITY_NONE ) ;
my_serial_stream.SetNumOfStopBits(1) ;
my_serial_stream.SetVTime(1);
my_serial_stream.SetVMin(100);

cout<<"Sending Command:\n";
my_serial_stream << buffer;
//my_serial_stream << printf("%s",buffer);
//my_serial_stream << "EXEX*\n123456789\n#";
my_serial_stream.read(next_char,100);
cout<<"Result: "<<next_char<<"\n";
my_serial_stream.Close();

return 0;
}
```

I also tried both of the commented out lines, and neither worked. The device does not receive the proper characters on the other end.'

I'm certain that this is pretty basic, perhaps something is grabbing the control characters in the middle? If anyone has any ideas on a better way to do this, I would really appreciate it. Specifically, I might need to send a byte with a value anywhere between 1 and 40, depending on the length of the data I wish to send to the printer.

My apologies for being unclear, please let me know if I need to break this down farther.

Many thanks,

Tom

Comment: *"perhaps something is grabbing the control characters"* -- Assuming the serial port is setup for canonical mode, then there is a setting that will convert `\n` to `\r\n`.  Type `stty -F /dev/ttyS0`, and look for `ONLCR` or `-ONLCR` (enabled versus disabled).

Comment: Good thinking, sawdust. However, it does not appear that ONLCR is set: `root@dc5000:~# stty -F /dev/ttyS0
speed 19200 baud; line = 0;
intr = <undef>; quit = <undef>; erase = <undef>; kill = <undef>; eof = <undef>; start = <undef>; stop = <undef>; susp = <undef>; rprnt = <undef>;
werase = <undef>; lnext = <undef>; flush = <undef>; min = 100; time = 1;
ignbrk -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke`

Comment: Well, I still have nothing here. It has to be one of the line-ending flags or something, but I cannot put my finger on it. If I hook another PC up to the serial port with a null cable, what is the easiest method to get the raw data for what was sent? `cat /dev/ttyS0 > somefile.txt` and then `hexdump somefile.txt`?

Comment: To view the raw data, I'd just use gtkterm or cutecom with hexadecimal output turned on.

Answer (score 0):

The line you send doesn't include the # that you mention in the character sequence.

Have you checked serial comms works on /dev/ttyS0 using gtkterm / cutecom etc?

To test your interface you could read back the serial port.  If you have a second port or computer, you could do that by connecting to another port via a null modem.  Otherwise you could short pins 2 and 3 of your serial port and check that you are receiving back the characters you send.

You may want to check the return values of the calls to make to the serial library, to see if any errors are returned.

Perhaps there are timing requirements on the printer, and you may need to wait between sending some characters.

I compiled the code and checked the output on another serial port with gtkterm, it does receive the string you would expect:

45 58 45 58 2A 0A 31 32 - 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 0A    EXEX*.12  3456789.

It won't affect the sending part of the code, but the receiving looks suspicious.  If the read() member function is like the system call and if next_char is a character array, then it won't null terminate the string.  Instead you have to look at the return value to get the size, and then null terminate if you are going to use it as a null-terminated C string.

Comment: sj0h: Thanks for pointing out that I had left out the '#'. That was just a typo, though, not part of my problem., and I fixed it above. I am able to control the device using screen/minicom/cu, but I cannot just 'echo "V" /dev/ttyS0' to have "V" sent to the port, for some reason. I'll have to give this a shot with a null cable or a looback plug.

Comment: I also just noticed that you were right about the null-termination on read. That was the subject of another question I had asked, and the easiest solution I found was to initialize the variable when declaring it: `char somevar = "";`

Comment: I just had a look at the class documentation, and SerialStream is derived from iostream, which is where the read() method comes from. This read seems somewhat broken, as it won't say how much was actually read, so you may be better to either just read one character at a time, or use the readsome() method which returns the number of bytes read. you can then null terminate the string if necessary by setting read_array[read_length] = 0;  Otherwise, you would have to first set the whole block to zeros with memset() or similar.